# Best method for communicating between devices running same app

Tags: android, communication

I want to develop an app which will send information (images mainly, but also information on how the app should display these images) between multiple devices devices...very much like apps such as drawSome etc. users should be able to select contacts who also have the app installes and start games etc.

What is the best method for going about this. I have read about GCM but also read that it has quite a lot of limitations.

if anyone could point me towards a tutorial as I cant find exactle what I'm after!

Thanks